# simple network between xp & 7 with cross cable problem

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking, computer-name

I have a simple network between Windows XP and Windows 7 with crossover cable.

---

Windows 7 computer is acting as a router with two LAN cards (onboard and PCI).

Onboard card settings:

- Obtain an IP address automatically
- Preferred dns server : 81.91.129.67
- Alternate dns server : 4.2.2.4
- Shared

So everything should be okay on Windows 7 computer.

PCI card on Windows 7 computer:

- IP address: 192.168.2.11
- Netmask: 255.255.255.0
- 0.0.0.0
- Computer name : cougar
- workgroup : nethome

Everything is off in network options except File & Printer sharing.

---

PC with Windows XP:

- IP address: 192.168.2.12
- Netmask: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.2.11
- DNS: 4.2.2.4, 8.8.8.8
- computer name : tiger
- workgroup : nethome

---

Both have connection to internet, and both can see each other by using IP (`\\192.168.2.11` and `\\192.168.2.12`).

Problem is when in XP I try to go to `\\cougar`, it says there is an error with network path.

In Windows 7 PC `\\tiger` works perfectly.

**What might be the problem with Windows XP PC?**

Few days ago this network was working okay, when both computers ran Windows XP.

Another problem is that I can't find `tiger` in "Homegroup" in Windows 7 PC. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: thanks 4 edit \ i learned from it \ any idea about my question?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://serverfault.com/questions/239012/simple-network-between-xp-7-with-cross-cable-problem).

Comment: so sorry \ i am new here and there and i tought i am in the wrong place (mean here 4 no answer)